# How can I prevent inline code running when I import my module?

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have made a program named `barcode.py` which had 4 functions and the main code.

When I import this into another program by using

```
import barcode
```

it runs the program barcode and asks for input like in the main program. I was surprised that this happens even when I have not yet called a function and have only imported `barcode`

Could someone please explain why this happens and how I can import my code without running the the main code in the file `barcode.py`?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your question came to me in a review queue for help and improvement in question answering style. I have edited the English to make it easier to understand, formatted code (see [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) and edited the title to summarise the problem you have encountered. It would benefit from a **further improvement** that I can't make - an outline of the code in `barcode.py` so that any answer can address the specific structure of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your problem is not `IDLE` specific.

The Python [documentation on importing modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules) tells you that:

> A module can contain executable statements as well as function
>   definitions. These statements are intended to initialize the module.
>   They are executed only the first time the module name is encountered
>   in an import statement. (They are also run if the file is executed
>   as a script.)

What this means is that when you `import` a module, it will be run once as if you had called it directly as a script (e.g. by typing `barcode.py` at a command prompt in your example).

If you want script in a module file that is executed if you call is standalone (e.g. by `barcode.py`) but not when it is `import`ed, use the following pattern, from [Python module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("I've been run as a script")
```

#### Example to check this functionality

You can check at a command prompt that this works - if you save the script above as e.g. `modulefile.py` and run

```
$ python modulefile.py
```

you will see

> `I've been run as a script`

If you start `python` and type

```
>>> import modulefile
```

You will get no output.

Comment: In other words, your top-level code other than import, def, and class statements should probably be put inside a new `def main():...` followed by `if __name__ ...: main()`

Comment: Indeed so - adding the `def main()...` name is a common convention to deal with this.  Happy for you to edit that into the answer if you want (I'm not posessive :)), or I can do so.